# Using PRG pattern with return button

Tags: php, readability

Hey guys, I haven't used the rpg pattern before, and had a quick question.
I want to be able to provide a return link to the page that submitted the post, but I don't want it to show up in the end url (because the return link is long, it looks really bad.  Not helpful when I'm going for human readability).  Is this possible? Or do I just need to deal with it?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Isn't that what the back button of the browser is for? Isn't the PRG pattern there to make the back button work?

Comment: Yes, to be more specific, I am building a cart, and wanted to add a 'Return to shopping' button.  It would be an added touch.  And the PRG pattern was created so people wouldn't inadvertently break websites, with the side effect of 'fixing' the back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found that `$this->session->set_flashdata()` does the job just fine.